# Wrong order in PriorityChannel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to setup integration flow, in which messages are processed in particular order.

I'm trying to do this with PriorityChannel, passing comparator:

```
public IntegrationFlow simpleIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jpa.inboundAdapter(this.entityManagerFactory)
                    .entityClass(DmmMessage.class)
                    .expectSingleResult(false), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
            .transform(list -> {
                System.out.println("\n----- NEW LIST:");
                return list;
            })
            .split()
            .channel(
                    new PriorityChannel(
                            Comparator.comparing(msg -> ((DmmMessage) msg.getPayload()).getMessageType() * -1)))
            .handle(msg -> {
                System.out.println("> " + ((DmmMessage) msg.getPayload()).getMessageType() + " with id=" + ((DmmMessage) msg.getPayload()).getId());
            }, endpointSpec -> endpointSpec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
            .get();
}
```

There are what is prints (result isn't consistent, changes every time I run, sometimes it's correct):

```
----- NEW LIST:
> 292 with id=1
> 292 with id=13
> 219 with id=9
> 219 with id=10
> 219 with id=11
> 219 with id=12
> 219 with id=14
> 292 with id=4
> 219 with id=15
> 214 with id=7
> 213 with id=6
> 212 with id=5
> 210 with id=2
> 210 with id=8
> 202 with id=3
```

I do not understand why line #8 not #3.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison happens on the elements when the are present in the queue, but you are able to poll existing from the queue (see your `Pollers.fixedDelay(100)`), it is really a fact that a new incoming cannot be ordered because there is nothing to compared with in the queue any more.

I don't a reason in the `PriorityChannel` in your use-case since you can query them from the DB in the required priority. Then when you split them and emit, everything is going to be ordered right way.